# How to get float value from object wrapped float in the sam way?

Tags: c++, class, templates

PI'm trying to wrap float, int, etc primitves value into my SParam class. But I have some problem with getting values from this struct. I want to use this struct as I use for example floats.

```
   template<class T>
    struct SParam
    {
        T value;

        SParam()
        {
        }

        operator T() const
        {
            return value;
            }
        };
    SParam<float> a;
    a.value = 4;
    printf("%f", a); //<--this don't print a.value
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with using the "naked" `SParam<float> a` with `printf` (or any other function that takes a variable number of arguments, for that matter) is that the compiler does not know that you want to pass a `float`. That is why the type-specific conversion is not applied. If you call a function with a specific parameter type, say

```
void printFloat(float f) {
    printf("%f", f); 
}
...
SParam<float> a;
a.value = 4;
printFloat(a);
```

then the compiler would figure out from the signature of `printFloat` that your conversion to `float` needs to be applied, and everything would work as expected. Of course you can always apply the conversion manually:

```
printf("%f", (float)a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to call `a()` in the printf, not `a`.
`a` is just an object of type `SParam`, you'll probably need to modify the operator definition to specify a return type of T as well..

for comparison try using `float x = a;` it should give you an error.  `float x = a();` should not however